# YouTube Data API Resumable Video Upload Request Error

Tags: php, httpwebrequest, youtube-api

I have video files stored on my web server which I want to be able to upload to YouTube in an automated kind of way. These videos are created on my website, which then the user can just upload to their YouTube Channel.

I am trying to make HTTP request calls to automate this video upload process, according to the Resumable Video Upload process here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_resumable_uploads

Everything works fine (getting the user's access permission, sending the metadata of the video) until the final step, which is the upload of the video itself. When I make the PUT request, it returns a response code 417 and says Invalid Request. Like this:

The following error was encountered:

```
Invalid Request
```

Some aspect of the HTTP Request is invalid. Possible problems:

```
Missing or unknown request method
Missing URL
Missing HTTP Identifier (HTTP/1.0)
Request is too large
Content-Length missing for POST or PUT requests
Illegal character in hostname; underscores are not allowed
```

I took a look at all those suggested possible problems, but I cannot find a fault anywhere in my code.

And the error message is just to vague and not specific enough to tell me where the problem is.

I am performing every step of the video upload process using the PHP's standard Http Request class. (http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.httprequest.php)

Here is my code:

```
$videoFile = *Some Video File*;

$httpRequest = new httpRequest($_SESSION['youtube_data_api']['upload_url'], HttpRequest::METH_PUT);

$httpRequest->setContentType('video/mp4');
$httpRequest->setPutFile($videoFile);

$headersArr = array('Content-Length' => strlen($httpRequest->getRawRequestMessage()));
$httpRequest->setHeaders($headersArr);

$httpMessage = $httpRequest->send();
```

I dug around on the internet a lot regarding this question, and a lot of times what I found are people using the Zend framework's YouTube library to accomplish this instead, which is a lot easier. Unfortunately, with the size of my website right now, it is just not feasible to spend some much time trying to integrate framework into my website.

Any insight into this problem would help tremendously! Thanks!

Comment: Did you debug and check that your file object is succesfully created and file is opened to read?

Comment: FWIW, you don't have to integrate the entire Zend framework into your application in order to use the GData library components. They're fairly modular.